# Is it possible to write constructor assignment operator only mentioning specially -copied members?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have class with N members. Most member are copyable. Only one member needs manual copying code.

Is there method to write copy assignment operator in such a way that I write code only for nonstandard member, and letting compiler generate copying code for all/other members ?

Comment: *Why* does that member need manual copying code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, of course, wrap your member in a separate class with a user-defined copy-constructor. And for the class you are talking about, write no user-defined copy constructor.

E.g.

```
class MyMemWrapper
{
   define copy constructor
};

class MyClass
{
   member 1;
   member 2;
   ...
   MyMemWrapper
};
```

Comment: Amazing, but why didn't you inherite MyClass from MyMemWrapper instead of making it a member?

Comment: +1 Only correct answer. Not sure why people trip over this so much: if I asked "I have a class with N members, but one is a pointer so I need to give it the right semantics, can I do write my assignment operator so I don't need to touch the N members?", people never suggest base classes or member grouping structs or flat out "no", they suggest a smart pointer. This isn't any different: *wrap the resource up*! Why is a resource with special value semantics outside of its wrapper?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: Why? I want my resource to be a member, not a base.

Comment: @GMan: But if you make it a member, you will have to pass through this member to reach members inside it. while with inheritance, you don't have to. And if you want to make your members private in the inherited class, you can make them public or protected in the father and inherite as `MyClass : private MyMemWrapper` .

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: Yes, and? I have to use a mutex's interface to manipulate the internal system mutex. I have to use a smart pointers interface to manipulate the stored resource. There's nothing new here. If the resource is meant to be used *directly*, then *it* needs to be the one to have proper copy-semantics.

Comment: +1 added note: if the class MyMemWrapper is only used by MyClass (and a some other cases), then i'd also nest it in MyClass. you can also apply the inverse: placing all default copyable fields in a nested class. which is best depends on the ratio of copyable/noncopyable, and how you'd prefer to organize them.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you override the copy assignment operator, compiler will not generate default copy assignment operator method to copy the standard members, as you intended.